# Questions on locationManager

Tags: java, android, location

this is the code I copied from other user. I have a few questions about that.

1. why the getLocation(Context context, Location result) method return a boolean instead of Loction directly?
2. In getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) method, what is the purpose of "result"?
3. Why there is an abstract class(LocationResult) with only an abstract method?
   (I tried to override the method in myActivity and it doesn't work, why?)

   ```
   public class MyLocation {
   Timer timer1;
   LocationManager lm;
   LocationResult locationResult;
   boolean gps_enabled=false;
   boolean network_enabled=false;

   public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
   {
       //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
       locationResult=result;
       if(lm==null)
           lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
       try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
       try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

       //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
       if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
           return false;

       if(gps_enabled)
           lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
       if(network_enabled)
           lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
       timer1=new Timer();
       timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
       return true;
   }

   LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           timer1.cancel();
           locationResult.gotLocation(location);
           lm.removeUpdates(this);
           lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
       }
       public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
       public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
   };

   LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           timer1.cancel();
           locationResult.gotLocation(location);
           lm.removeUpdates(this);
           lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
       }
       public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
       public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
   };

   class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
       @Override
       public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
            if(gps_enabled)
                gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
       }
   }

   public static abstract class LocationResult{
       public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the getLocation(Context context, Location result) method return a
>   boolean instead of Location directly?

It will return true only if the providers were enabled and location updates were requested.

> In getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result) method, what is
>   the purpose of "result"?

That is where you register your class that implemented LocationResult

> Why there is an abstract class(LocationResult) with only an abstract method? (I tried to override the method in myActivity and it doesn't work, why?)

It is a callback. When a location is obtained, this method will be called.

[Please read about callbacks and how they're used in Java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip10.html), only then you should try out this code

Comment: I think I am requested to override the abstract method in myActivity. I tried to I tried to do so but it doesn't work, why?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it will be much simpler if your make `LocationResult` an `interface` which your activity can implement. Else, do this : `MyActivity  extends LocationResult {`

Comment: I did something similar to this, I created a class NewLocationResult extends LocationResult in MyActicvity and Override gotLocation method, but when I do this: newLocationResult.gotLocation(), it is still entered the abstract gotLocation() method